# How to track a single marker in multiple calibrated cameras in opencv

Tags: opencv, 3d-reconstruction

There are lots of functions in opencv that relates to 3D reconstructions.
I have multiple cameras that I calibrated them with opencv. so I have the extrinsic and intrinsic and essential and fundamental matrix of whole cameras.

I know that a good algorithm in order to track a marker in 3d space is triangulation. Is there any good implementation of triangulation in opencv or perhaps an external library to handle triangulation is a proper way ?

Also if I understand correctly the 3d location of the marker is based on one of the camera's coordinate system. How can I get the 3d coordinate of the marker based on the true ground coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate [Structure-from-motion](http://code.google.com/p/libmv/) (SFM) and [bundle adjustment](http://www.ics.forth.gr/~lourakis/sba/) (BA) algorithms.